# How to deploy static website to Azure Storage Container from Bitbucket

Tags: php, continuous-integration, bitbucket, azure-blob-storage

I have a php website hosted on azure as a webapp. Deployment happens through Bitbucket - I push code from dev machine, bitbucket triggers azure,  azure publishes the repo from Bitbucket.

Now, I created a new project (repo) and moved the static content (css, js, images) of website from webapp project to the new project.

I am trying to use azure storage container to deliver all the static content instead of the compute instance.

I referred [Static Content Hosting Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589776.aspx) and related links and understood how to do the static content delivery but could not find (googled a lot) how to implement continuous integration from bitbucket to storage container.

Is it doable? Any links or suggestions?

**Edit-1**: There are about 150 static files altogether and in any commit, only 2 or 3 files will get updated. There could be upto 5 pushes to Bitbucket repo per day. I thought of writing a script that uploads all 150 files to storage container for every commit but that does not seem to be an efficient way.

Comment: I believe the current answer to this is 'no'. You'd probably need to use [Bitbucket webhooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) feature to send a payload request to the specified URL when push event happens, then in your application server consider calling some Bitbucket REST APIs to get a list of the files which were actually changed, then upload those files to the storage container.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I was under the impression Bitbucket Pipelines would be able to do this but now I'm not so sure. It doesn't help that Azure storage data isn't organised into folders.